# How to Renew SSL Certificate on Amazon Web Services/Apache

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I got this problem for about a week now, My client ask me to renew the SSL certificate which expired already. I followed a lot of tutorials already but nothing help me.

I have this certificates provided:

- Private Key
- Intermediate Certificate
- CSR
- Public Certificate

The server is Amazon and uses Apache/HTTPD

I saved the private key as .key file and the rest is .crt

By the way, I setup the ssl.conf because that is where the Virtual Host is located.

I saved my certificates in, **/etc/httpd/conf/ssl.cert/**
I saved my keys in, **/etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/**

and the location of my ssl.conf: **/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf**

My questions are:

1. What's the usual way on renewing SSL Certificates?
2. What's all I need to renew it?
3. Can I do it only on the FTP client or I need to go to my AWS page and set it up there?

I am really desperate to get out of this embarrassment. I hope someone would help me do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CSR (certificate signing request) that contains the server's information. (There are many, many guides on how to do this using openssl.)  You then purchase a SSL certificate from your certificate issuer of choice and provide them with the CSR. When your order is complete they will issue you a SSL certificate that you can download and install in Apache. If you go to the issuer of the original certificate they will likely have a renew process that will walk you through all of the steps.